# Why I can't ask questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions

If I try to ask a question I see a page that say me this:

> You have reached your question limit It looks like you might need a
>   break - take a breather and come back soon!
>
> You've asked 2 questions recently, some of which have not been
>   received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own
>   pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your
>   questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account
>   from asking questions entirely.
>
> It's been 4 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you
>   wait 1 days before asking again. Use this time to revisit your
>   previous questions, editing to address any issues that folks have
>   pointed out in comments.

This say that I have post 2 question recently "that have not been received very well". But I have only post 1 question on serverfault and it have no negative rating. So why is the system telling this?

Thanks in advance

PS:  @Dennis Kaarsemaker I didn't delete any question. I have just noticed that I can't put comments also.

Comment: Did you delete any of your questions?

Comment: [FYI, if you're trying to make that question-asking ban last longer, you're doing a good job](http://serverfault.com/q/639986/118258).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The message you're seeing comes from a recently implemented question rate limiting system, which you can read more about in [the Help Center](https://serverfault.com/help/asking-rate-limited). In particular, please note:

> If you haven't yet done so, please read our advice on [how to ask good questions](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask), and [the types of questions one should avoid asking](https://serverfault.com/help/dont-ask).
>
> This block is only temporary, but much longer blocks exist in the system. We're trying to slow you down and provide you with more guidance now, in hopes that you avoid a much longer period where the system won't accept questions from your account. Please take some time to revisit and improve your previous questions wherever possible.
>
> You'll be welcome to ask questions again soon, but please make sure you research your problems prior to asking, and ask only when you're really stuck. When you do need to ask, be sure to follow the guidance we've provided and everyone will have a much better experience.

---

Why you are seeing this message? You actually have asked two questions on Server Fault.

The first question you asked was [wordpress multisite failed to import media and users](https://serverfault.com/q/610314/126632). This question was downvoted to -2 and [automatically deleted by the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/189912) after 30 days with no answers. (I think this question would be better suited for our sister site, [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), but I never saw it originally and it's too late to migrate it.)

The most recent one was [Update ubuntu automatically](https://serverfault.com/q/638895/126632). This question received both an upvote and a downvote, making it eligible for question rate limiting.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't remember this question... and I don't remember to delete it because it was deleted by the community no by me. I will read more about forum guidelines to improve my questions in the future.